# How to run gnome-terminal -e "source activate" without permission denied error?

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, permissions, scripts

How can I run "source activate" from a bash script as the -e argument to gnome-terminal?

```
gnome-terminal -e ". /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate"
```

When I run this command, I expect a new terminal that has the command `source activate` already run. But instead, I get an error in both the current window and the newly created one:
Error: Failed to execute child process "." (Permission denied)

I feel like I am making a simple oversight, or misunderstanding the -e argument perhaps.

Running the command in a bash script or a terminal window gives the same result. `sudo` gives the same result, so I'm thinking the permission issue indicates that I am not doing what I think I'm doing with the command above.

Comment: Check to see which user owns that directory and try using that user.

Comment: same user. But this may be an XY problem, because I am expecting the window to stay open and let me use the terminal as the sourced environment. But doing gt -e "vi" gives me vi, and if i quit, the terminal closes. i may close the question

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `.` (`source`) is a shell-builtin i.e. shell-specific command, not an external one. You need to run it inside shell; Without the shell, `gnome-terminal` is trying to execute a literal `.` command with `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate` as its argument, leading to permission denier error.

You need to spawn an interactive shell to do the sourcing and spawn another interactive shell afterwards:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -ic ". /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate && bash"'
```

As you trying to initiate a virtual environment, you might want to set the `--rcfile` option instead, cleaner approach but the obvious caveat is that the common session startup files `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` are not read:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash --rcfile /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate'
```